# Connect to an SSH server

Tags: go, ssh

I'd like to make a program that will allow me to do that:

```golang
./my_app connect prod
```

After this command, I'd like to be logged in that server as I would have typed manually `ssh user@ip` where user and ip would be guessed inside the program.

I don't know if it is possible to run a command and attach to the process created

Comment: How cross platform do you want your application to be? If you just want to use it on linux, the easiest wait is to call [`syscall.Exec("/usr/bin/ssh", ..., os.Environ())`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Exec). This will replace the current process with the ssh process.

Comment: @DylanReimerink thank you for your answer. It works!


I'm kinda new using Go. Lot to learn.

Thanks again!

Comment: I posted the comment as answer so the question can be marked as answered

Comment: See also [golang.org/x/crypto/ssh](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh)

Comment: @JimB thanks i'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use it on linux, the easiest wait is to call [`syscall.Exec("/usr/bin/ssh", ..., os.Environ())`](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#Exec). This will replace the current process with the SSH process.